# installing urllib in Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I would like to import urllib to use the function 'request'. However, I encountered an error when trying to do so. I tried pip install urllib but still had the same error. I am using Python 3.6. Really appreciate any help.

i do import urllib.request using this code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error 
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt') 
counts = dict()
for line in fhand: 
    words = line.decode().split() 
for word in words: 
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
print(counts)
```

but it gives me this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'urllib.parse'; 'urllib' is not a package

[here is a screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrfl.png)

Comment: What OS, what were the errors etc?

Comment: i'm using windows. i edited the question with more details and a screenshot of the problem. please check it.

Comment: Did you try `from urllib import request`?

Comment: How did you install Python3? Please try to give all the information so people can answer your question.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: You saved your code in file `urllib.py` and it is your problem. `import urllib` first tries to load file `urllib.py` in local folder and it loads your file instead expected module..

Answer (score 57):

`urllib` is a standard library, you do not have to install it. Simply `import urllib`

Comment: i did, but still not working. i edited the question with more details and a screenshot of the problem. please check it.

Comment: Or from urllib import request

Comment: @mohamed You did not import exactly as stated in t answer

Comment: @ArthurTacca thank you very much man! it's working with your edit.

Answer (score 7):

`urllib` is a standard python library (built-in) so you don't have to install it. just import it if you need to use `request` by:

```
import urllib.request
```

if it's not work maybe you compiled python in wrong way, so be kind and give us more details.

Comment: i do import urllib.request using this code:

    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

    fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')

    counts = dict()
    for line in fhand:
        words = line.decode().split()
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
    print(counts)

but it gives me this error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'urllib.parse'; 'urllib' is not a package

Comment: @ahmed i edited the question with more details and screenshot, please check it.

Comment: Your code above works fine with me (just replace line 2 with `fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt') ` ) without any ModuleNotFoundError exceptions, are you sure you have python 3.6 ? and if yes are you have python 3.6.3 or something else ?

Comment: i have python 3.6.3

Answer (score 5):

The corrected code is

```
import urllib.request
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand: 
    words = line.decode().split() 
for word in words: 
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
print(counts)
```

running the code above produces

```
{'Who': 1, 'is': 1, 'already': 1, 'sick': 1, 'and': 1, 'pale': 1, 'with': 1, 'grief': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your local module named `urllib.py` shadows the installed requests module you are trying to use. The current directory is preapended to sys.path, so the local name takes precedence over the installed name.

An extra debugging tip when this comes up is to look at the Traceback carefully, and realize that the name of your script in question is matching the module you are trying to import.

Rename your file to something else like `url.py`.
Then It is working fine.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

yu have to install the correct version for your computer 32 or 63 bits thats all

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt',context) 
counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    words = line.decode().split() 
for word in words: 
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
print(counts)
```

Comment: try this. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```py
import urilib3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).